# List of kAB*** properties?

Tags: cocoa, addressbook, appkit

The AddressBook framework has a list of constants, like `kABFirstNameProperty`. I'm wondering if there's a list of those that I could display in a user interface, other than having to "replicate" this myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C-based Address Book API for the Mac, there's [a function named `ABCopyArrayOfPropertiesForRecordType`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/C/ABAddressBookRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABCopyArrayOfPropertiesForRecordType) that sounds like exactly what you need.

I would hope that the property keys would be equal to those in the Objective-C AB API, if that's what you're using, but you should probably test that—or just use the C-based API.

Comment: Nope. Not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a list of "all" properties, not only those set for a contact.

Comment: @StuFFmc: The function is “…ForRecord*Type*”. It gives you all properties that are possible for records of the specified type (e.g., ABPerson).

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Yeah that function doesn't seem to have been implemented in ObjC. I don't mind using the C function but although it works in the Console, in the code, the compiler complains it doesn't know `kAbPersonRecordType`. Any idea?

Comment: Not **yet** marking it as the *answered* because I'm not yet 100% sure it's the right thing. Here's what it gives back: `(lldb) po (NSArray*) ABCopyArrayOfPropertiesForRecordType(ab, kABPersonRecordType)
(NSArray *) $1 = 0x00000001005ca830 <__NSArrayI 0x1005ca830>(
com.apple.Messages.FontSize,
com.apple.etag,
HomePage,
InstantMessage,
AIMInstant,
First,
YahooInstant,
ICQInstant,
Address,
JobTitle,
Creation,
ABPersonFlags,
BirthdayComponents,
Email,
ABRelatedNames,
MSNInstant,
Modification,
ABDepartment,
RemoteLocation,
com.apple.collectionpath,
Middle,
..., FirstPhonetic,
ABDateComponents
)`

Comment: So yeah I marked it as **answered** now, but I still have a problem with the way I would identify the `com.apple.***` (which are `__NSCFString`) and the `__NSCFConstantString` (which are *real* properties). One way is checking if the returned value from `ABLocalizedPropertyOrLabel` is the same, but it's not super awesome. In any cases, Peter, THANKS for the pointer!

Comment: @StuFFmc: `kABPersonRecordType` is declared in the headers for the C API, and it looks like AddressBook.h “intelligently” only includes one set of headers or the other, according to your module's language (if you're writing in Objective-C, it imports the Objective-C headers). You'd have to import ABGlobalsC.h directly. I found a better solution, though—see my new other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the Objective-C API's equivalents to the `ABCopyArrayOfPropertiesForRecordType` function. Two methods:

- [`+[ABPerson properties]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABPerson_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/ABPerson/properties)
- [`+[ABGroup properties]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABGroup_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/ABGroup/properties)

Since these are class methods, you should find that they return all known properties for any records of that type.